# Smooth edges when varying the size of a ggplot2 geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a visualization I'm making thick curves using `geom_path`:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(Hmisc)
len=50
edge=data.frame(bezier(x=c(0, 1, 2), y=c(0, 1, 0),evaluation = len))
edge$Sequence <- sin( seq(0,pi,length.out=len) ) 
ggplot(edge,aes(x = x, y = y, size = Sequence)) +  
  geom_path() + 
  scale_size( range = c(.3, 20), guide = F) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) + ylim(0,.6) + 
  scale_alpha(guide=F)
```

This works well except that the individual segments are disjointed:
[image: example]

Obviously I can increase `len` which improves things but this is a) slow for the complex graphs I'm creating b) unsatisfying.

Is there a straightforward fix beyond trying to hack the `ggplot2`/`grid` source?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "hacking the source". You probably want a new primitive.

Comment: sounds like a job for geom-ribbon or geom-polygon, depending on whether you want a single filled shape, or many individual pieces

Comment: @baptiste I think geom_polygon might be the way to go: some of my curves turn back on themselves (i.e. x -> y is 1 to many) so I think that rules out geom_ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a job for geom-ribbon or geom-polygon, depending on whether you want a single filled shape, or many individual pieces

Comment: sorry about that - meant to post as comment, somehow I can't find the option to delete with the app interface..